# Neo4j is not starting post database shutdown due to lack harddisk space

Tags: neo4j

Here is the Error (The host machine was restarted as well):

org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by this virtual machine

Answer (score -1):

try to delete the .lock files if any

Comment: you mean the store_lock file. As I don't see any *.lock files.